# Blade, parse variable from within a string

Tags: laravel-4, laravel-blade

I would like to achieve something like this:

```
$data['username'] = "John";
$data['msg'] = "Hey {{$username}}, blab blab blab";
View::make('view.name')->with($data);

// Blade

{{ $msg }}

// Prints
Hey John, blab blab blab
```

Any ideas on how to go about that?

**EDIT:**
I am trying to achieve "mailchimp" like messaging system, where the user (this is only admin side and so far admin is just me so I can overlook a couple of security checks here) can add variables (which i know will be available within view scope) to the message body. I am using this for support, so for instance I might want to send a link to a user's profile :

```
Hey {{first_name}},

This is a link to your profile: <a href="/users/{{user_guid}}">profile</a>
```

So that means that there might or might not be variable within the message body.

EDIT:
the close i got is with (that might help understand what i am trying to do) :

```
// These variable are not hard coded here, I just had them to indicate that they will be in view scope
$data['username'] = "John";
$data['msg'] = "Hey {{$username}}, blab blab blab";

// I can only know for sure that 'msg' will be defined and that it may or may not contain over variables
$data['msg'] = Blade::compileString($data['msg']);
View::make('view.name')->with($data);

// Blade

{{ $msg }}

// Prints
Hey John, blab blab blab
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$data['username'] = "John";
$data['msg'] = "Hey " . $data['username'] . ", blab blab blab";
View::make('view.name')->with($data);

// Blade

{{ $msg }}

// Prints
Hey John, blab blab blab
```

But if the username is defined by the user, and not hardcorded - then you should print it like this in blade to prevent XSS errors

```
{{{ $msg }}}
```

Edit:

Could you do something like this?

```
$data['msg'] = "Hey %s, blab blab blab";
{{{ sprintf($msg, $username) }}}
```

Comment: Thanks @The Shift Exchange, though I can't use that syntax in my case, i've added clarification in my questions.

Comment: Yeah that's closer though it would be hard to maintain when writing message with multiple variables.

Answer (score 1):

You can use View::make to do this:

```
$string = View::make("view.name", array("username" => "user", "msg" => "blah blah"));
```

Later you can do this:

```
$parsedView = $string->render();
```

Works like a charm! :)